# Formatting response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a set of data where i need to format and render in HTML.

This is the data :

```
var data = [{
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
        department: 'financial',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
        department: 'healthcare',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
        department: 'insurance',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
        department: 'Realestate',
        group: 'groupB'
    }, {
        name: 'Mark',
        age: 20,
        department: 'financial',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        age: 21,
        department: 'insurance',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        age: 21,
        department: 'financial',
        group: 'groupB'
    }
];
```

Here i have multiple users where he belongs to different groups and department.I want to format in such a way the if he belongs to same group then get the department which he belongs to in array and for other department show that as a new object.

The response should look like this:

```
var data_formatted = [

    [{
            name: 'john',
            age: 20,
            department: ['financial', 'healthcare', 'insurance'],
            group: 'groupA'
        },
        {
            name: 'john',
            age: 20,
            department: 'Realestate',
            group: 'groupB'
        }

    ],

    [{
            name: 'Mark',
            age: 20,
            department: ['financial', 'insurance'],
            group: 'groupA'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mark',
            age: 21,
            department: 'financial',
            group: 'groupB'
        }
    ]


];
```

Any suggestions Please!

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Is the source data generated by you? if so, could you show us how?

Comment: I am getting this data from AJAX call from back end

Comment: You should probably look into how this Json string is generated, and make changes there. If you don't have access to this code, just use the `$.jsonParse()` function to parse that string into an object and loop over it to create new department lists for each user.

Comment: @sree3505577 but you generated it or not? beause formatting the way you want should be done in the back-end

Comment: It is not about parsing the JSON it's about grouping and formatting.

Comment: You're probably better off performing that grouping/coalescing on the server side. For example, if you are using MySQL to generate that output from your API endpoint, `GROUP BY` clause will be helpful.

Comment: @sree3505577 You need to parse it first, before grouping and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.

```js
var data = [{
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
        department: 'financial',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
        department: 'healthcare',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
        department: 'insurance',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'john',
        age: 20,
        department: 'Realestate',
        group: 'groupB'
    }, {
        name: 'Mark',
        age: 20,
        department: 'financial',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        age: 21,
        department: 'insurance',
        group: 'groupA'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mark',
        age: 21,
        department: 'financial',
        group: 'groupB'
    }
];

var data_formatted = [];

var byname = _.groupBy(data, function(element){return element.name});
_.forEach(byname, function(element){
  var bygroup = _.groupBy(element, function(element){return element.group});
  _.forEach(bygroup, function(element, key, groups){
    var departments = _.map(element, 'department');
    element[0]['department'] = departments;
    groups[key] = element[0];
  })
  data_formatted.push(_.values(bygroup));
})

console.log(data_formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @sree3505577 glad to hear!